# why there is a difference in total emi amount and amount spent from my credit card

Tags: taxes, credit-card, india, ecommerce

I have purchased a watch from an e-commerce portal. The calculation page was like below

[image]

according to this, I have to pay

> 919.38 x 6 = `5516.28`

But, they said total payable amount is `5278.79` Also, I found in my credit card statement that they have deducted the same. Note that the product value is `5395`

Since the bill was not generated for my credit card for this month, I'm totally confused !

Now, Do I need to pay
**919.38 x 6 = `5516.28`**
or
**879.79 x 6 = `5278.79`**

These hidden charges are totally confusing, I made this purchase in **`India`** So, Kindly help me understand this tough subject.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the closest I've come to figuring it out:

```
Subtotal:       5278.79
Convenience fee:  99
GST:              17.82
Interest:          4
Convenience fee: 116.82
                -------
          Total 5516.43

Installments:    919.38
Periods        x   6
                -------
          Total 5516.28
```

Those two totals are ₹0.15 different, which I can't resolve.  Maybe there's a rounding error on their side.

Anyway, you must pay a total of ₹5516.28.

Comment: This is cheating. I opted for 'no cost emi' and they are actually charging intrest(4 rupee) on that and putting convience fee 2 times. This is punishable offence right !

Comment: @VikasAcharya I don't know enough about Indian ecommerce to pass judgement on legality.